# slow perfomance team city check out over TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, teamcity

I have a Team City Server, and TFS 2010 with de TFS DB in other server.
Both Are Virtual Machines over a ESX Server (monster server for virtualization)

The thing is, from VS 2010, check-in, check out are pretty fast
But From team City, the checking for changes process of the Build configurate take around 15 minutes or more, 
The size of the Collection Database its 400 MB (its not than big) el sise of the all the code of the project about 16 mb including packages

Everything runs over LAN configuration

the Team city server had installed VS team explorer 2010 and  net framework and SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your TeamCity version take a look at this issue http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-13046

> Current implementation of TFS checking for changes on the build agent will start 'tfs-native.exe' process per one include rule. For this example there could be huge overhead in starting/stopping, connecting/disconnecting, negotiatings.
>
> The workaround for 5.1.x and early 6.0 could be to set 'teamcity.tfs.use.remoting.server' property with value 'true' on the TeamCity server. See http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/TeamCity+Startup+Properties for more details.

It solved the issue for us